# RxJS Update State and Passthrough

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, angular-httpclient

I have a user library that is used across several Angular apps in my organization. As a refactor/new version, we are looking to move towards a state-based service, with an interface with something like this:

```
export interface UserService {
    user: Observable<User>
    getProfile(url: string): Observable<User>
    updateProfile(url: string): Observable<User>
}
```

This way, consumers can bind components to `UserService.user` knowing that the data will always be up-to-date, and call get/update functions in buttons or background activity, etc.

**Clarification:** The user library is meant to be used in apps that use `ngRx`, as well as those that do not want something as heavy, but still want observable-based user binding.

So I wire up the functions like this (with slight variations) :

```
public getProfile(url: string): Observable<User> {
    const obs = this._http.get<User>(url);
    obs.subscribe(profile => this.setProfile(profile));
    return obs;
}
```

Where `setProfile` updates an internal Subscription that `UserService.user` returns in a read-only manner.

Once of my consumer apps uses `ngRx` for the rest of it's state management. When consuming my library, we notice some oddities:

1. When wrapped inside of an `ngRx` effect, sometimes any functions using Angular's `HttpClient` will be called several times. To rectify this issue, any function I have using `HttpClient` ends with `.publishLast().refCount()` to ensure the HTTP call is made only once.
2. If a call fails, the consumer cannot catch the exception. For instance, `this.authService.getProfile().catch(error => alert(error))` will never get called. To get around this, I am now modifying my functions on their subscribe: `obs.subscribe(profile => this.setProfile(profile), error => Observable.throw(error));`

Is this normal behavior when implementing a "state-store" service in Angular?

**Edit:** Sample ngRx effect (please note that this is real implementation, what I posted above is way simplified from our actual implementation):

```
public BiographyUpdate: Observable<any> = this._actions.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActionTypes.BIOGRAPHY_UPDATE),
    map((action: BiographyUpdate) => action.payload),
    switchMap(bio => this._auth.update(`${Environment.Endpoints.Users}/users/sync/biography`, action)
      .map(profile => new BiographyUpdateSuccess(profile.biography))
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("AM I BEING HIT?");
        return Observable.of(new BiographyUpdateFailure(error.toString()))
      })
    )
  );
```

Comment: can you share ngrx effect code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you call the `subscribe` event, it is fired and the result resolved (correct result or error) inside the subscribe method. So at the time, you call `this.authService.getProfile().catch` method, the asynchronous event is already fired and finished. That is why it's not calling.

You can either move the `catch` operator in the `getProfile` or you can return the observable from `getProfile` without subscribing to it.

```
public getProfile(url: string): Observable<User> {
    return this._http.get<User>(url)
            .pipe( tap( profile => this.setProfile(profile))); 
}
```

Now subscribe it through the `authService` service

```
this.authService.getProfile()
  .subscribe(profile =>  // do the work)
  .catch(error => alert(error))
```

Comment: Thank you! Let me give this a try.

Comment: Worked very well! Thanks so much!